# Cordova platforms installed: iOS broken

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I cloned a remote repository that has the platforms already, when I run the following I get 'android broken iOS broken'. What does this mean by broken and is there a fix other than removing the platforms and re-adding?

```
cordova platforms ls
```

Answer (score 0):

The right thing is to remove, then re-add:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add ios
cordova platform add android
```

Comment: I have a Cordova app that builds fine for both ios and android but when I run the "Cordova platform ls" command it says both ios and android are broken. Is there truly no way to fix this other than the cordova platform rm/add commands?

Comment: @Christopher That's right. Remove and Add is the right way, this also applies to Cordova plugins. There is no "synchronize" operation.

Comment: Just following up here - it is possible that when I was getting the "android broken" platform ls I was in a Powershell terminal instead of a standard command prompt terminal. Just had a similar experience and when I closed the PS terminal and went into a command prompt terminal add platform rm/platform add I got the correct result (no more "broken" nonsense). Argh /headdesk.

Comment: It happens. Glad I could help answer your question.